# Rails active record query, serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Suppose I have Users data that store array of pet in String datatype

```
[
  #<User id: 1, name: "John", pets: "---\n- cat\n- dog\n- bunny\n- ''\n">,
  #<User id: 2, name: "Pete", pets: "---\n- dog\n- bunny\n- ''\n">,
  #<User id: 3, name: "Jack", pets: "---\n- cat\n- ''\n">,
  #<User id: 4, name: "Kurt", pets: "---\n- cat\n- bunny\n- ''\n">
]
```

Can i get all users that has a cat? Maybe something like `User.find_all_by...` or `User.where(....)` or anything that return as a relation? So i can order with active record query.

I know i can get all users that has a cat with

```
User.all.select{|s| YAML.load(s.pets).include?'cat'}
```

, but it convert to array that cannot be ordered with active record query.

thx for helping.

Comment: check this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record

Answer (score 3):

You could use simple SQL to see if 'cat' shows up in the serialized column.

`User.where('pets LIKE "%cat%"').all`

Comment: it will also retrieves "catfish"

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize your data, add Pet model and set has_and_belongs_to_many association between theese models.

Comment: for some reason, i prevent to add another model. it's ok for me, if there's no better solution. thx