# Ruby-On-Rails: Finding DB entry that has a certain array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I have a model TestRun that has an array entry `:machine_ids` that is an array of integers. How will I be able to call find with conditions so that I can find the specific TestRun entry whose field `:machine_ids` has a specific array entry `mid` and a `:status` "Running".

This is a rough outline of what I want. I do not know how to format the conditions for finding if the array contains `mid`.

```
cur_testrun = TestRun.find(:first, :conditions => {:machine_ids => mid, :status => "Running"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array will serialize into YAML for storage in your database. Serialized data doesn't lend itself to easy or efficient querying.

As suggested in the question & answer below, you could try normalize the schema a little. Alternatively you're left with the SQL 'like' query which won't be fun to write if your matching gets complex.

[Rails active record query, serialized array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962923/rails-active-record-query-serialized-array)