# ActiveRecord where clause error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie to rails.I have a model called OfflineExport. In the table I have data like this

```
#<OfflineExport id: 2, 
  parameters: 
      {"project_id"=>"3", 
       "type"=>"submissions", 
       "filters"=>{"task_type"=>"", 
       "corrections"=>"", "grade"=>"", 
       "min_duration"=>"", "after"=>"", 
       "max_duration"=>"", "reviews"=>"", 
       "before"=>""}, 
  "send_email"=>"true", 
  "options"=>{"offline_record_id"=>2}}>
```

Am trying to fetch parameters["project_id"] in where clause like

```
 OfflineExport.where("parameters[project_id] = '3'")
```

But am getting error like:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  cannot subscript type text because it is not an array
```

can anyone help me in solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a serialized column in your model. Something like this: `serialize :parameters`. This means the data is stored in the database not in an easily readable format, which leads that you can not query on it. [Same as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record).

Solution: extract the field you want to query on, and make a column for it.

Comment: So you mean i have to use " MyModel.all.select { |m| m.mycode.include? 43402 }" like this now?

Comment: Not really. A similar solution can work (this one is obviously not written for your schema), but that would slow your program heavily. You should create a new column for that data, and query on that.

Comment: Here the situation is i cannot extract the field separately into another column..is there any other way?

Comment: You may try to write a `like` condition to it, but that is quite dangerous, and you need to study the stored string. Or you can use the technique on the link, so loading all the elements, and then selecting on code side. It is slow, but a working method.