# Need to find all "Clubs" where column "userlist" contains "current_user.id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to find all "Clubs" where column "userlist" (which contians an array of user ids) contains "current_user.id".

Here is the line of code in the controller that I am trying to use to accomplish this:
`@userclubs = Club.where('userlist in (?)', current_user.id).all`

I end up with an empty array: `[]`

This is the code I am using in the view:
`<%= f.association :clubs, :collection => @userclubs, :label_method => :name, :value_method => :name, :as => :check_boxes, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' %>`

If I change the controller code to `@userclubs = Club.all` I get all of the clubs as check boxes, but I only want the ones that the user belongs to to show.

I am probably going about this all wrong, but I am new to RoR and can't seem to find the proper way to do it.

Comment: What is the column type of `userlist` and what database are you using?

Comment: The type is **text** and the database is **pg**

Comment: Please disregard this message.

Comment: So can you explain what you mean by `userlist` "containing an array of user_ids"?

Comment: I did try `Club.where(:userlist => current_user.id)` and just tried the other... I always get something like _#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x5b7d7b0>_ unless I add the `.all` to it, then I just get the `[]`

Comment: `userlist` contains a serialized array of user_ids. It is working for me to display a list of current users in the "Club" on the "Club" show page, but I can't seem to make a query that looks for the current_user.id in that array.

Comment: OK, not what I wanted to hear, but looks like that is the case.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `where` method is thin layer over SQL. Your attribute is only an array in the eyes of Rails. From the database perspective, `userlist` is a text field and you can only search it as a text field.

While searching serialized structures is generally not practical, as discussed in [Searching serialized data, using active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record), in the case of flat array, you could do a regex search of the column looking for user_id in question, taking care to insure that the user_id is surrounded by the appropriate separate characters, something like:

`userlist rlike ...`

where `...` is the constructed regex including `?` for the value of `current_user.id` surrounded by the appropriate separate characters.

Since you're using Postgres, you could change the column datatype to be a native `array`, but that would only be a marginal improvement, as described in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html under "Searching Arrays".

Unless you have an extraordinary situation, it's best to store relationships like this use the Rails association mechanism.

Comment: After following the links you provided and working at it a little, I have gotten it to work until I try to make the check boxes. Is there a way to set the `:label_method =>` and `:value_method =>` when I only have an array of names (i.e. `[Club 1, Club 2]`)? I really want the label and value to be the same.