# Finding objects with certain value in serialized attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model with a [serialized](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) (Array) attribute.

I've been trying the query advised [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555151/3205492):

```
MyModel.where("my_attribute = ?", [43565, 43402].to_yaml)
```

but it only returns an empty `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

**How should I query to find objects with a certain value in a serialized attribute?**

Model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password validations: false
  belongs_to :organization
  serialize :actions, Array
end
```

The column type is `String`.

Comment: Post your `Model` code.

Comment: Would be useful to see what the value you're trying to match is; and the SQL being produced by ActiveRecord

Comment: I've tried to match both a number without quotes and with quotes. When I call for the object's attribute I get an `Array` with two inserted numbers: [2, 9]

Answer (score 0):

Forget about Rails for a second and go to SQL. How is it stored in the database? Is an integer type, string type? You need to match that specific column for this to work. Ruby can do the parsing and the proper ActiveRecord query. However, your SQL database is the one doing the finding.

Not sure if this answers your question directly. But it should send you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I still haven't solved it, this kind of advice is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN command

```
MyModel.where("my_attribute IN(?)", [43565, 43402])
```

you can also use NOT IN