# Rails - Search by store attributes in model

Tags: mysql, configuration, store

How i can search using :token and :external_code

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :admin
    has_many :lessons
    store :config, accessors: [:token, :external_code]

    has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

i tried

```
prod = Product.find_by({
        token: callback_params[:token],
        external_code: callback_params[:code]
     })
```

but... this error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products.token' in 'where clause': SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`token` = 'Q1LhyCrBsYqt57tRVUgnjmHbyZ0zf81110916' AND `products`.`external_code` = '320552' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.where("token = ?", callback_params[:token].to_yaml, callback_params[:code].to_yaml)
```

read this for more information:
[Searching serialized data, using active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record)

Answer (score 1):

You must first define one for your store format

```
store :config, accessors: [:token, :external_code], coder: JSON
```

To make the search I found nothing in Rails API providing for it. As it is not appropriate to use the search on store I used SQL own resources to make the query

```
Product.where("products.config LIKE ? and products.config LIKE ? ", '%"token":"meu token"%', '%"external_code":"meu code"%')
```

gives to turn this into a generic method easily and put in some abstract class, but roughly that's it