# Rails query by nested key/value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, serialization, hashmap

I just learned how to [tag a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108372/rails-query-by-record-association/33108489) and query by that tag, but I'm not sure if it applies to this situation. I would like to have a column on my model that contains a hash of arbitrary keys (i.e. they may or may not be different per record) with values, and then I would like to be able to query by those key/values.

So something like this:

```
my_dog = Pet.new
my_dog.traits = {
    :weight => 20,
    :has_shots => true,
    :color => 'brown'
}

their_cat = Pet.new
their_cat.traits = {
    :weight => 4,
    :has_shots => false,
    :color => 'brown'
}
```

I know I could serialize this data if all I wanted to do was output it later. But what I'd like to achieve here is the ability to then query these records by keys in this hash. For example (obviously wrong query syntax): `Pet.where(traits: 'weight < 25 AND color = "brown"')`.

Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: If you use postgres and the hstore column data type http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-hstore-with-rails.  The link you refer to is tagging with a join table, why would you use a hash?  There are many benefits of the join table.

Comment: You could use the Rails' built-in `serialize` method but it would be very difficult to make SQL conditions on these serialized values. If you are using PostgreSQL, take a look at HStore like @Swards said. If not using PostgreSQL, I recommend you to use another table (something like `PetTrait` holding a `pet_id`, and `trait_name` and a `trait_value`). Then the conditions will be a lot easier to do in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can define scopes on `Pet` to query based on the values you want (class methods work for this as well, but here are some thoughts on when to prefer one vs the other: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/should-you-use-scopes-or-class-methods/).

Some examples:

```
scope :max_weight, -> (weight) { where("weight <= ?", weight) }
scope :min_weight, -> (weight) { where("weight >= ?", weight) }
scope :has_color, -> (color) { where("color = ?", color) }
```

Then, assuming you have access to the tag variables you want to filter by, you should be able to call `Pet.max_weight(25).has_color('brown')`.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like each scope has to be defined in the class, though, right? What I am looking for is a way to filter by an arbitrary value, if that makes sense. So if 3 `Pet` records contain `[:traits][:has_black_spots] = true` I want to be able to filter down to just those 3 records. Not all `Pet` records will have `has_black_spots`, though, so I wouldn't want to create a specific scope for it. Make sense?