# SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: parameters.user:

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am saving a list of followed users to the db and then trying to get the records where the current user is a part of that list but keep getting this exception.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: parameters.user: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities"  WHERE "parameters"."user" = 3
```

This is a record in the db

```
=> #<PublicActivity::Activity id: 107, trackable_id: 16, trackable_type: "Shout", owner_id: 1, owner_type: "User", key: "shout.shout", parameters: {:user=>[3]}, recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2015-10-20 21:44:41", updated_at: "2015-10-20 21:44:41", read: false>
```

These are the queries I've tried that give me this. current_user.id = 3

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where({'parameters.user' => current_user.id})

PublicActivity::Activity.where(parameters: {user: current_user.id})
```

So. How do I get the records where the current user is a part of that list of users? Also, would the I be able to use the same query in Mysql?

Comment: Might seem like a silly question, but is the parameters column defined as a serialized column in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might seem like a silly question, but is the parameters column defined as a serialized column in the model? With adapters like MySQL and (I believe) SQLite you *can't* query serialized  fields. So If it's something that you'd like to query, you need to save it separately from the serialized field.

That being said, with PostgreSQL and their rails adapter, you *can* query serialized fields.

You should check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record) and [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13214464/2639561)

Comment: That was it. The gem I'm using has parameters serialized. But it kinda sucks I can't do anything simple about it.