# How to get an attribute from a Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search form for searching in a specific model (Order). It works fine but i want to add in my search method a parameter from an association (transactions) which is nested like this: ["params"]["transaction_id"].With the code below, i get an error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders#index`  because i cannot express it in the right way. How can i fix this?

**Model:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"

  def self.search(params)
    query = order('created_at DESC').joins(:transactions)
    query = query.where('name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? OR phone LIKE ? OR address1 LIKE ? OR state LIKE ? OR city LIKE ? OR **params.transaction_id** LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%").order('created_at DESC') if params[:search].present?
    query
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
  @orders = Order.search(params)
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],id: "search_text", placeholder: "   Search order" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-success", id: "search_but_order" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Solution**
As @Lanny Bose suggest me, i create a new column for my Order model and i passed it the value of the serialized params to it. With this way i can now add it to my search method.

Comment: Do you mean you're searching on the transaction's id attribute?

Comment: yes but it is in the association model 'transactions' and it is nested.

Comment: Then you want `transactions.id` not `params.transaction_id`

Comment: No it is nested like this `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<OrderTransaction id: 118, order_id: 124, action: "purchase", params: {"transaction_id"=>"5795241933376546"}`

Comment: So you're serializing the parameters and storing them in the database?

Comment: @japed yes i serialize them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93468/discussion-between-gregory-ynwa-and-japed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching serialized data, using active record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I begin, you have one logical error in `Order.search`. You are setting `query =` twice, which means you're just writing one query over the other. You want to chain them together.

As for how to construct the query, you're on the right track.

**Model**

```
def self.search(term)
  if term
    Order.order('created_at DESC').joins(:transactions).where("name LIKE :t OR email LIKE :t", t: term)
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Note the new syntax around `:t`. Rails calls that Placeholder Conditions [in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions), and it will mean you don't have to copy your search variable over and over.

Also, I realized I only compared against `name` and `email`. I'll let you type in the rest of your fields. :)

**Edit**

Sorry, I neglected to spell this out. I would do the params processing in the controller, so I'm just passing a string to the model.

**Controller**

```
@orders = Order.search(params[:search])
```

...and that's definitely an issue of style over substance, I believe.

Comment: Nice and DRY your code but it doesn't work. Also my problem is how to access the ["params"]["transaction_id"].

Comment: I made an edit. If it's still not working for you, can you be more specific with what errors are appearing?

Comment: `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`. In my view i iterate in my @orders variable. The seems to be in this line  `<% @orders.each do |order| %>`

Comment: Can you try the query in Rails console with a value you are certain is in the database?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: In your terminal type `rails console`. Then type `Order.search("something")` where something is a term you know is present in your transactions table already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93471/discussion-between-lanny-bose-and-gregory-ynwa).

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way. if you column is serialize then you can used `.to_yaml` converter before passing your searching string in this case you needs to create same hash as you are seriallize at time of store

we can create your string using yaml as:

```
 yml_str = {:transcation_id => params[:search] }.to_yaml.gsub("-","").squish
```

you can used `.squish` and `gsub` method to remove unwanted `---` and `\n` from string

simply your query from specific column as

```
Order.includes(:transactions).where("order_transactions.params like ?", "%#{yml_str}%")
```

Your method

```
def self.search(params)

    query = order('created_at DESC').joins(:transactions)
    query = query.where('name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? OR phone LIKE ? OR address1 LIKE ? OR state LIKE ? OR city LIKE ? OR order_transactions.params LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{yml_str}%").order('created_at DESC') if params[:search].present?
    query
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using scopes?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :name, -> (name) { where("name like ?", "#{name}%")}
  scope :email, -> (email) { where("email LIKE ?", "#{email}%")}
  scope :phone, -> (phone) { where("phone LIKE ?", "#{phone}%")}
  scope :address1, -> (address1) { where("address1 LIKE ?", "#{address1}%")}
  scope :state, -> (state) { where("state LIKE ?", "#{name}%")}
  scope :city, -> (city) { where("city LIKE ?", "#{city}%")}

  scope :custom, -> (field, value) { where("#{field} LIKE ?", "#{value}%")}

end
```

Now we can solve the nested params problem the following way:

```
q=params[:search]
if q.present?
   result = Order.name(q).or.email(q).or.phone(q).or.address1(q).or.state(q).or.city(q)
    if params[:nested_query]
       hash.each do |key, value|
          result=result.or(key,value)
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: I have never use scopes. I will try it and i wil let you know.