# Query sqlite hash column in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sqlite

I have a column in a table saved as a hash and I'm trying to use sql to query the column to find records. So far I can return all records using the query that I found. So, how do I expand upon it to be able to find records with parameters by `id` **and** `provider`? Also, are there any good tutorial on how to use sql queries in rails?

```
<PublicActivity::Activity id: 233, trackable_id: 2, trackable_type: "User",  owner_id: 2, 
owner_type: "User", key: "like", parameters: {:id=>"27", :provider=>nil}, 
recipient_id: 3, recipient_type: "User", created_at: "2016-01-16 18:26:27", 
updated_at: "2016-01-16 18:26:27", read: false, user_recipients: nil>
```

This is the query.

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where("parameters LIKE ?", "%id%")
```

Also, When I try this

```
PublicActivity::Activity.where("parameters.id LIKE ?", "%27%")
```

I get this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: parameters.id: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities"  WHERE (parameters.id LIKE '%27%')
```

Comment: Most likely you can't. But to tell you why, we need to see the lines from the model that describe this field.

Comment: Its from a gem and the field is serialized. So, If I run `PublicActivity::Activity.last.parameters` I get `{:id=>"27", :provider=>nil}`

Comment: Why can't I do this btw?

Comment: Serialization happens inside the app, not inside the database. Hence, database has no knowledge of the structure and can't cut out specific keys. SQLite that is. Some others can, e. g. PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. Is there any kind of way to use sql to just iterate over the parameters column and get matches for `id` and `provider`?

Comment: You serialized it, so no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching serialized data, using active record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record)

Comment: what column should contain the serialized hash data?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ providers

Answer (score 1):

What about?:

```
Activity.all.parameters.where('id like ? AND provider like ?', '%#{id}%', '%#{provider}%')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this last `.all` is not needed

Comment: @MichalSzyndel you are right, I will edit my answer.