# Not like on Array field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

here is the problem I'm stuck with:

I'm using Rails 4 & MySQL

I've Message which have one sender and one recipient.

I want to be able to archive messages but if sender archive a message, the recipient still can access to the message until he archive it too.

I've serialize a field :

```
serialize :archived_by, Array
```

which contains which user archived the message

but I can't figure out how to query with it.

```
Message.where("archived_by like ?", [1].to_yaml)
```

works well, returning messages archived by User '1'

```
Message.where.not("archived_by like ?", [1].to_yaml)
```

won't work, returning nothing

I would like to find something else than using a classic many to many ...

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I finally decided to add 2 fields, one for the sender & one for the recipient to know which archived the message. If someone has the proper way to do this, tell us :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgresql you could query the informations.
As in answer [Searching serialized data, using active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record) described, the downsize of `serializer` at least under mysql is, that you byepass native db abstraction.

Comment: I'm using MySQL but can't use select or whatever because I need to be able to paginate, so it should be a parameter in the query

Comment: `pagination`- then you should start a new question