# rails: How to find entries with empty arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-console

I've got an issue finding empty arrays in a SQLITE table.

I serialized the `product_category` param, which works well for saving arrays into my DB, as follows:

```
serialize :product_category, Array
```

The following is query to find all empty arrays for this param, but its giving me an `nil` error:

```
Product.where(product_category: []).first
```

How do i find Products where the product_category has no values in its array?

I tried using `{}` instead of `[]` as suggested in a similar POSTGRESS related question.

Does anyone know the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this on mysql, this works for me, please try.

```
#product.rb
serialize :product_category, Array

#rails console
>> product = Product.new
>> product.product_category = []
>> product.save
>> Product.where("product_categoty = '[]'") #It returns the last record that we have just created.
```

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into it, power. sadly this doesnt work for sqlite.

Comment: can you try using like query on serialized array, Product.where("product_category LIKE '%?%'", "")

Comment: you can also check this link which suggest don't use #serialize for any data you need to query on. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record)

Comment: This ` Product.where("product_category LIKE '%?%'", "")` gets me all arrays containing an empty value, but i want to only find those with a complete empty array. thanks though.

Comment: @Daniel: I have updated my answer, please try. And let me know if it works for you, Thanks!