# Search in rails serialize column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I know it's bad to search in `serialize`, but I encounter this problem.

I got a model called Question and contain a serialize column `assignments`

```
id question_set_id  assignments
1   1               {"12982": true, "12332": true}
2   2               {"12222": true, "12332": true}
3   3               {'11111': true}
```

And I got a array called `group_ids`

```
group_ids = ["12982","12332"]
```

I need to find the record who contain at least one `group_id` in `assignments`.

So, the result of this example should be like

```
[
    {
                     :id => 1,
        :question_set_id => 1,
            :assignments => {"12982": true, "12332": true}
    },
    { 
                     :id => 2,
        :question_set_id => 2,
            :assignments => {"12222": true, "12332": true}
    }
]
```

I've tried

```
Question.where("assignments IS NOT NULL").where("assignments LIKE '%?%'", 12982)
```

It seems works, but how to apply an array?

And according this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555151/3732906), I tried

```
Question.where("assignments IS NOT NULL").where("assignments= ?", groups_ids.to_yaml)
```

However, it return a blank array.

Comment: Which database do you use (postrgesql/mysql)? Which serializer do you use (JSON, Hash, Custom)? Which type is your serialize column (Text, JSON, hstore)?

Comment: mysql, JSON and Text

Answer (score 0):

With mysql 5.7.? you can query JSON data directly. I didn't try it but following the docs something like

```
Question.where("JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(assignments , 'one', '$[*].assignments.12982', '$[*].assignments.12332') == 1")
```

should work. You can furthor more convert your column from text to JSON data type and get validation of the json document and optimized storage.

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.6, it looks very hard to use. I think I should just modify my serialize column to many attributes.

Comment: If you have to query json data via SQL and your database does not support JSON queries then it is a good choice to refactore your data model.