# How to fetch records from database which contains a search value from a serialised column, in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `model` called `exchange`. in this i have a `serialised` column `emp_ids`. i want to fetch those records which contains the user search value in the `emp_ids` column. How can i query this?

`emp_ids` column looks like this `["1","2","3"]`. my `search value` will be `"2"`. then i want to get only those records from database, which contains my search value in `emp_ids` `serialised` column.

i am looking for a `query` that looks something like this.

```
Exchange.where(:emp_ids.include?("1"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching serialized data, using active record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

> Exchange.all.select { |m| m.emp_ids.include? "1" }

Comment: but, this is making a database query first. after that it is filtering the records. i want a query where it fetches only those records from the database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to fire 'IN' query on the emp_ids column, Try Following:

```
Exchange.where(emp_ids: [1,3])
```

For more details check here for subset conditions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions