# Is there any way I can query a text in rails with db postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-audited

Here is the table structure

```
create_table :audits, :force => true do |t|
    t.column :audited_changes, :text
end

class Audit < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :audited_changes, Hash
end
```

This is bunch of code from gem Audited gem where I need to query text field audited_changes which is stored as serialized hash.

Found a reference where we can query for serialized array in text [Searching serialized data, using active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record), Do I have any option similar to that for querying rather that looping tons of records?

This is how I'm taking out the records I need from a audited_changes

```
fields = ['name', 'description']
audit_data = audit_data.select do |obj|
    obj.define_singleton_method(:audited_changes_filtered) do
        obj.audited_changes.select {|k,v| fields.map(&:to_s).include?(k) }
    end
    obj if fields_present?(obj, fields)
end
```

Comment: Do you have to use `serialize`? That's a horrible hack and parsing YAML inside the database is going to be a big mess.

Comment: Ya @muistooshort Its a gem concept, I can't change now as the db already has more than 50k records

Answer (score 0):

### Query raw content of the serialized text column (may work only in some cases)

Assuming there are are two records:

```
Audit.create(audited_changes: {'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'})
Audit.create(audited_changes: {'key3' => 'value3', 'key4' => 'value4'})
```

Check how it looks in psql (how values are stored in PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT * FROM audits;
 id | audited_changes 
----+-----------------
  1 | ---            +
    | key1: value1   +
    | key2: value2   +
    | 
  2 | ---            +
    | key3: value3   +
    | key4: value4   +
    | 
(2 rows)
```

So values serialized in YAML

Query raw content of the text column to search record with key **key3**:

```
Audit.where("audited_changes LIKE '%\nkey3:%'")
```

This probably will work in your case.

Also you need an index for full-text search for fast querying.

Comment: tried this, didn't work. Do I have any other option other than looping the data? User can specify what field changes they need to see, according to that I need to restrict the data