# Rails ActiveRecord join with an array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create an ActiveRecord query in my Rails application that involves an inner join of two tables, though one of the records I'm trying to join on is an serialized array (string). For example, I have three tables in total. The associations look like this:

- Car:

  ```
  serialize :categories_id, Array
  belongs_to :postings
  belong_to :categories
  ```
- Category:

  ```
  has_many :cars
  has_many :postings, through: :cars
  ```
- Posting

  ```
  has_many :categories, through: :cars
  has_many :cars
  ```

This is my `cars` table (notice the array):

```
select cars.* from cars

id: 23,
posting_id: 10,
categories_id: [1, 5, 20]
```

This is my `categories` table:

```
select categories.* from categories

id: 20,
name: "BMW"
```

This is my `postings` table:

```
select postings.* from postings

id: 20,
title: "First title",
description: null,
value: "open"
```

The join I want to create is similar to this:

```
select categories.* from categories inner join cars on categories.id = 
cars.categories_id where cars.posting_id = 20
```

Except right now it's not returning any results, because the join on cars.category_id is an array. I'm basically wanting to return all the associated `categories` from the `categories_id` column in the `cars` table. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Step 1: Forget that `serialize` exists. Step 2: Use a separate table instead of that `serialize` kludgery. Step 3: ... Step 4: Profit. `serialize` is an ugly hack that sometimes seems like a good idea at the time but almost always leads to pain, suffering, and tears. Don't use it. Ever.

Comment: Step 5: You'll realize `serialization` has made your life hard when you're planning on integrating search.

Answer (score 0):

[Official document](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON) for ActiveRecord serializer specifies that the serialized attribute will be saved as YAML in the database. When you save the record or fetch the record the serailization and deserialization of the attribute to proper type(array in your case) happens on the ruby activerecord layer, not handled as array on the database layer.
This is the downside of using serialized attributes and we can are pretty much limited to loading and saving the data.

You can normalize your data with a new association  has_and_belongs_to_many using cars_categories table to support your usecase. cars_categories table can help you using through relation.

cars

```
belongs_to :postings   
has_many :cars_categories
has_many :categories, through: :cars_categories,  :source => :category
```

category

```
has_many :postings, through: :cars
has_many :cars_categories
has_many :cars, through: :cars_categories,  :source => :car
```

Hope this helps.

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814622/searching-serialized-data-using-active-record) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user3775217, it sounds like I shouldn't be serializing `categories_id`! Do you have any suggestions on how I can keep using an Array for the `cars.categories_id`, as my intention is to ultimately return the associated `categories` for each id in the array.

Comment: yes, i mentioned in answer you should look at a new table(cars_categories) to support belongs_to_and_has_many through relationship. cars_categories will have category_id and car_id to map cars belonging to multiple categories and vice versa.