# Query based on attribute's size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I wonder if it's possible in Rails 5 to do a `where` query for attributes of given length?

Let's say I have a serialized Array attribute called `tags` on the model `Post`, and I want to find all `posts` that have more than 3 items in that attribute.

I would envision it looking something like this:

```
Post.where('tags.size > ?', 3)
```

A great bonus would be if there's a solution for this in ActiveRecord.

Comment: A serialized Array will be just an opaque blob of YAML inside the database, the database won't know what to do with that YAML so you're out of luck. Track the `tags` size by hand in a separate column, stop using `serialize` (it is a trap after all) and use a separate association table, or switch to a database that supports arrays (such as PostgreSQL). I repeat: `serialize` is a trap that might give you short term gains but almost always blows up in your face.

Comment: That's reasonable advice, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, as commented by @mu is too short, and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814796/6548745), **do not use serialize when you need to query that attribute**.
Referring to that answer again, you can try something like this,

```
Post.all.select { |post| post.tags.length > 3 }
```

P.S. Not tested. Even if it works, seems very inefficient.

If you plan to switch on to create an associated model called `Tag`(which is better ofcourse) you can do something like

```
Post.joins(:tags).having('count(tags.id) > 3').group('posts.id')
```